# Dynamic Table cell to be filled when triggering a method

Tags: c#, dynamic-tables

I'm working with ASP.NET an C# I have a dynamic table and I want a cell to have an initial value then I want to use this value as a parameter in a method and fill the same cell with another value....

here is snippet of my code

```
 for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) { 

     List<Hotel> h = listHotelList[index];

    Hotel myHotel = new Hotel();

    mytable = new Table();
    mytable.ID = "HotelTable"+index;

    Page.Form.Controls.Add(mytable);
    mytable.CellSpacing = 20;
    mytable.CellPadding = 10;


    for (int g = 0; g < h.Count; g++)
    {
        myHotel = h[g];
        TableRow row = new TableRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();


            if (i == 0)
            {

               // I want to leave this with only the value of the hotelId
               // and I want my method to fill this cell with an image by retrieving 
               // the value of the hotelId 
            }

            if (i == 1)
            {

                Label tb = new Label();
                tb.ID = "label1_" + g + "Col" + i;
                tb.Text = "<h4>" + myHotel.hotelName + "</h4><br />";
                cell.Controls.Add(tb);


            }

            row.Cells.Add(cell);

        }


        mytable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    }
```

for my case I'm taking a hotel Id from the cell when the user click a button then it trigger a method that would take the value in the cell "hotel Id" and retrieve the image for this particular hotel and fill the cell with the image

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you don't see the tabel?

If so,
add the table to your page

```
    Page.Controls.Add(mytable);
```

If the positioning is not good, then put a placeholder on your page, and add the control there.

```
    Placeholder.Controls.Add(mytable);
```

Comment: No, I want to reserve a cell with some value then I want to take this value and do some manipulation with it then replace it with another value... for my case I'm taking a hotel Id from the cell when the user click a button then it trigger a method that would take the value in the cell "hotel Id" and retrieve the image for this particular hotel and fill the cell with the image.

Comment: a table contains cells which you can manipulate through TableCell.text and you can set a image per cell